# Setting CATALINA_HOME by another batch file parameter?

Tags: windows, variables, syntax, batch-file, command

- I have two batch files. first.bat and test.bat

first.bat:

```
 @echo off

SET START="C:\Users\Neonous\Desktop\test.bat"

call %START% "C:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat_6"
```

test.bat:

```
 @echo off
 set "%CATALINA_HOME%=%~1"
 echo %CATALINA_HOME%
```

actually what am trying is, just want to set CATALINA_HOME value for that session(not permanently), by calling test.bat with one parameter, inside first.bat file.
Error: the syntax of the command is incorrect

how to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

first.bat

```
@echo off
call "C:\Users\Neonous\Desktop\test.bat" "C:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat_6"
```

test.bat

```
@echo off
set "CATALINA_HOME=%~1"
echo %CATALINA_HOME%
```